# Figure out a way to add chosen restaurants to my app with just a click of a button

Tags: firebase, api, web-scraping

I'm building a app I want it to have a scrollable list of restaurants andnonly show restaurants that i pick. I was hoping to be able to go on to Google maps on my phone and save a restaurant and then have that show up on my app. There is a way to share a website link of your favorite places on Google maps and I was thinking of using a web scraper but I was told that won't work either. I am building a app that Will show my friends favorite restaurants that I choose and I need a easy way to get these restaurants show on the app does anyone have an idea how to do it ? Like maybe send a link or text the link for a Google maps business listing and have those details put in to firebase I just feel that with today's technology there has to be a easier way then adding every restaurant and address phone pictures one by one

I tried to save restaurants to a list on Google maps and then share that list with a web scrapper but the link Google maps provides of your favorites does not give the correct names or any info its like jumbled information

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.